# How to automatically update mobile app (from Managed Google Play) with Microsoft Intune

Tags: android, google-play, intune

In Intune I added an app from Managed Google Play and assigned it to a device such that it was successfully installed and working on a device.  I then created a new release of the app in the Google Play console, and in Intune synced Managed Google Play, but the app did not automatically update on the device.  Can new app releases be automatically updated on devices?

As a workaround, in Intune, I unassigned the app, deleted the app, added the app again, and reassigned it, and it then installed the latest version to the device.

Further background - I am using the new multi-app kiosk mode but not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question but I am facing the exact same issue. We use intune in a single app kiosk mode with a managed google play application. 3 days ago we updated the application in google play and it is been availble for roughly 2 days now. But the MDM devices simply do not update. Except reassigning the application which is a VERY aggressive solution due to data loss, did you manage to find an official solution or explanation? Thank you!

Comment: I've the same problem with a single App kiosk mode. I've asked also to support but they reply me that for now is not allowed by design. Anyone found other workaround? thanks

Comment: @AlonMinski Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @white.devils did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @MossPalmer Hi, eventually we called their tech support. I provided them with all the device s/n that did not get the update. They saw that these devices were somehow "disconnected" from the mdm/intune servers. They reconnected the devices and updates went through. Nothing was done on our side. I would suggest checking the specific devices status in the status panel. Maybe there is some sort of indication there.

Comment: Thanks @AlonMinski I'll try that now. Thank you for getting back to me.